# Best practice when adding constraints programatically in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I am adding some constraints to an UIView programmatically in Swift. My question is when in the ViewController life cycle is it best to add the constraints? Should I add it in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, maybe even viewWillLayoutSubviews. Does anyone know if it even matters where I add the constraints?

Comment: any reason for the down vote? Im asking for best practices, there may be a point to when it is best to add the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter, because the constraints are merely a list of instructions as to what *will* happen at layout time. They do not depend upon the absolute sizes of anything. `viewDidLoad` is thus perfectly good, even though at that time things do not yet have their ultimate sizes - because layout time has not yet arrived.

Moreover, `viewDidLoad` has one huge advantage that neither of those others has: it is guaranteed to be called *only once*, while the others can be called many times (you wouldn't want to keep adding the same constraints over and over, would you?).

Comment: quick question, best place to add animation? viewWillappear or viewDidappear?

Comment: i was going to accept the answer, just waiting for the countdown